# How to search for text in all measures?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there any way to search for text in all the measures?

For example - suppose I want to find whether ColumnX is used in any measure then currently I have to look into each measure, is there a better/quicker way?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do you need to know this number for?

Also, if you can't manage to download external tools, you could make a copy of the PBI report and there you change the datasource to exclude your column. That way you could possibly do a manual count?

Comment: My goal is to remove 1 column from the model. The model is used in 2 places: 1. The model pbix file itself, and 2. Other reports via live connection. Both these reports have their own measures. Currently I have to open each report, click on each measure and read the formula.

Comment: Alright. If it is spread out over multiple reports then the answer of Andrey is probably the way to go. Because that would make my option very tedious work.

Comment: But his option is valid only for report that contains the model. My report has measures but it points to the model via live connection so I cannot use his approach.

Comment: I'm sorry I have missed that. 
I can't think of any other way than just doing it manually unfortunately. I thought about checking connections for a bit, but I suppose those will only point you towards the reports and not the measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [Power BI External Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-external-tools#how-to-register-external-tools) which will allow you to do that, for example this one - [Document Model](https://data-marc.com/2020/07/28/external-tools-document-your-power-bi-model/).

Or you can save your .PBIX report as a template (.PBIT), unzip it and look at the DataModelSchema.json file, where all measures are in plain text (more details [here](https://visualbi.com/blogs/microsoft/powerbi/exporting-measure-column-formulas-power-bi/)). According the OP, for Live connection reports, these can be found in `Report\Layout` file.

Comment: What if it is a report using live connection?  I cannot see `DataModelSchema.json`.

Comment: Then the measures are not in Power BI, but in the datasource. Look there.

Comment: No, the measures are in the Power BI report file. Its just that the report is using live connection.

Comment: Can you update your answer - Add to it that for a report using LIVE connection, the plain text is located in `Report\Layout` file